# Javascript styling for a specific url

Tags: javascript, url, styles

Here is my site: http://dkurf.esxsb.servertrust.com/ 
I need to create specific styling for this page: http://dkurf.esxsb.servertrust.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=dfhs
I don't have access to the html for that page so i need to override the styles that are throughout the site only for that page.

This is the bit of javascript the company that hosts my ecommerce store provided (Volusion, p.s. don't ever use them they are a css nightmare!)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[ 
if (location.pathname == "/ProductDetails.asp" || 
    location.pathname.indexOf("-p/") != -1 || 
    location.pathname.indexOf("_p/") != -1) 
    document
        .writeln("\n<style type='text/css'>.pricecolor{ background:#000; }</style>\n\n"); 
//]]> 
</script>
```

But if any one has any suggestions, it would be super helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see that script anywhere in the page.

Comment: Alright so the updated script worked great! But now my page is all jacked up. Any help?

Comment: `document.write*` whatever is generally a bad idea and should be considered deprecated. Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm not very well versed in javascript. Any suggested write ups?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should work.
Should theoretically fail if there's no `<head>` tag.

```
var appendStyle= function(css){

    var code = document.createTextNode(css);
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type='text/css';
    style.media='all';
    style.appendChild(code);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

};

(function(){
    var _ol = typeof(window.onload)==='function' ? window.onload : function(){};    
    window.onload = function(){ 
        _ol.apply(this,arguments);  
        if(window.location.href.indexOf('ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=dfhs')!==-1) { try{
            appendStyle("\
                .pricecolor{ background:#000; }\
                body{ background:#f0f }\
            ");
            alert('new style appended successfully');
        }catch(e){ alert('error appending style: '+e) }};
    }; 

}());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish absolutely. fixing now

Comment: Ok so that works! But, the effect is delayed. If you go to the page it will look normal, but after a couple seconds a pop-up will come up saying: style appended successfully. Any way to fix it so their is no delay and no pop up?

Comment: @user1510719 remove `var _ol = ...` 3 lines including that one, and the corresponding end bracket. `window.onload` makes it work after page has loaded completely but you'll have to make sure this code is in your body tag.

Comment: @user1510719 just remove the `alert()` calls

Comment: @user1510719 you're welcome. please make sure to upvote / accept this answer if it works for you.